# Not able to insert. Doesn't show any errors but doesn't insert as well

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

This is my insert statement. Records are not inserting but no errors showing also. Please help

```
protected void btn_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    if (btn_Add.Text == "Submit")
    {

        string Height = txtHeight.Text;
        string TopDia = Convert.ToString(txtTopDiaMeter.Text);
        string BottomDia = Convert.ToString(txtBottomDiaMeter.Text);
        string ShaftThick = Convert.ToString(txtShaftThick.Text);
        string BlackWt = Convert.ToString(txtBlackWeight.Text);
        string TotManHrPerPole = Convert.ToString(txtTotManHrPoleData.Text);
        string Plate_Length = Convert.ToString(txtPlateLength.Text);
        string PLATE_DIA = Convert.ToString(txtPlateDia.Text);
        string PLATE_THICKNESS = Convert.ToString(txtPlateThick.Text);
        System.Collections.Hashtable ht = (System.Collections.Hashtable)Session["UserDetails"];
        Int64 UsrId = (Int64)ht["UserID"];
        string CreatedBy = Convert.ToString(UsrId);
        string FoundBoltId = Convert.ToString(ddlFoundationBolt.SelectedValue);
        string PoleTypeId = Convert.ToString(ddlPoltype.SelectedValue);
        string ProductTypeID = Convert.ToString(ddlPdtType.SelectedValue);

        string Status = chkActive.Checked ? "True" : "False";
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadimages.PostedFile.FileName);
        fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Pole Data/" + filename));

        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["valmont"].ToString());
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into DEF_POLE_DATA_MST(Height,TopDia,BottomDia,ShaftThick,BlackWt,TotManHrPerPole,Plate_Length,PLATE_DIA,PLATE_THICKNESS,CreatedBy,FoundBoltId,PoleTypeID,ProductTypeID,Status,ImagePath) values(@Height,@TopDia,@BottomDia,@ShaftThick,@BlackWt,@TotManHrPerPole,@Plate_Length,@PLATE_DIA,@PLATE_THICKNESS,@CreatedBy,@FoundBoltId,@PoleTypeId,@ProductTypeID,@Status,@ImagePath)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", Height);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TopDia", TopDia);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BottomDia", BottomDia);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShaftThick", ShaftThick);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlackWt", BlackWt);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotManHrPerPole", TotManHrPerPole);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Plate_Length", Plate_Length);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PLATE_DIA", PLATE_DIA);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PLATE_THICKNESS", PLATE_THICKNESS);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", CreatedBy);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FoundBoltId", FoundBoltId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PoleTypeId", PoleTypeId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductTypeID", ProductTypeID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", Status);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImagePath", "~/Images/Pole Data/" + filename);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            BindGrid();
            Accordian.SelectedIndex = 1;
            JQUERYDisplay.ShowAlertMessage("Record Inserted Successfully");

            CleraFields();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            JQUERYDisplay.ShowAlertMessage(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

Here's the table:

[image]

Comment: It might be because `status` is keyword in your insert statement try to wrap it within `[]` so `[Status]` and see if it works

Comment: Open a profiler on the destination database to see first if the query is being executed at all.  If it's not, then check your connection to see where it is going or if the query is being executed at all.  If it is being exucuted, check the indexes to see if any have the IGNORE_DUP_KEY set to on.  Will also help if you post the actual sql executed from the profiler.

Comment: Why you convert all values to string also bigint fields (i.e.FoundBoltid, PoleTypeId, etc) ?

Comment: Then what's the alternative Max? Can you say? I'm new to c#

Comment: All fields must match same type of db, so in your code you must write `Int64 PoleTypeId = Convert.ToInt64("45");` but before you must check if ddlPoltype.SelectedValue have value or use `Int64.TryParse()` to ensure consistency, also check that the required fields have values.

Comment: that didn't work also :|

Comment: @Satyajit put this line `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;` before `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", Height);` this line

Comment: replace this cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); with this line int insertedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); and debug if insertedRows are zero then it means no insertion. also add this line cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; as @tinka suggested.